# Is there a benefit to using bind() when using SOCK_RAW on Linux in C?

Tags: linux, sockets, raw-sockets

When using raw sockets in Linux to send and receive data directly over the wire (wanting to skip the Linux TCP/IP stack) is there any benefit in callin `bind()` ?

Data can be sent and received over a phsyical interface by passing a sockaddr struct to the `sendto()` and `recvfrom()` calls as follows:

```
int tx_int = sendto(sock_fd, frame_buffer, 1514, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&sockaddr_ll, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));

int rx_len = recvfrom(sock_fd, frame_buffer, 1514, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL);
```

One can specify the interface in this method to transmit on when the `sendto()` call is made and which interface to pick up packets from when `recvfrom()` call is made. This is working fine for me but I have seen other people using `bind()` when using raw sockets. Is there some major short fall in not doing this?

Comment: FYI, passing a `sockaddr` to `recvfrom()` does not let you choose the interface to read on, it returns the address of the sender instead. And using `sizeof (sockaddr*)` is just wrong, use `sizeof (sockaddr_ll)` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks! Regarding the `sizeof` that was just a typo on my part, I have corrected it! Regarding `sockaddr`, ah OK I see now. Thank you.